# Install and configure the good locale for a postgresql error on ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, locale

Here is my error when i try to use postgresql 10  :

> DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8", 
>   which is not recognized by setlocale().

How to configure properly the locales ?

I've try : export LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

The message implies that `en_US.UTF-8` is not part of the available locales
(which can be displayed with `locale -a`)

To add it: `sudo locale-gen en-US.UTF-8`

Then PostgreSQL needs to be restarted to pick it up.

If this instance of PostgreSQL has been created by copying a data
directory from another machine, you also want to reindex the databases
(see `reindexb`) to account for any change in locales across systems.

Comment: on my ubuntu 18.04 I had to modify the hyphen to underscore and add quotes: `sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"`